# Issue with early message dispatching in NServiceBus 6. Batched message dispatch does not work?

Tags: nservicebus

We use NServiceBus 6 with transports MSMQ and RabbitMq. When we had MSMQ with distributed transactions, we never had message dispatched earlier than distributed transaction get committed. However when we turned it off and wrap it inside transaction scope manually we see that Nsb started sending messages before the handler execution is over. Our code looks like this

```
public Task Handle(ICommand1 message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
   using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
   {    
       HandleMessage1(message1);

       _session.Flush();
       tx.Commit();
    }   
}

private void HandleMessage1(ICommand1 message1)
{
    // Updating database
    ...
    // Sending other Command2 to separate handler
    bus.Send<ICommand2>(x =>
    {
       ...
    });
}
```

From logs I can see that ICommand2 starts handling earlier than ICommand1 handler managed to commit data changes in database, getting 'old' data, before Command1 handler get them updated.

I was under impression that we won't have this sort of problem since Nsb6 provides us with [Batched message dispatch](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/batched-dispatch?version=core_6). Looks like it's not a case for us, I wonder why and how we can fix that. I tried to run it under MSMQ (no distrib. transaction) and RabbitMq, result is the same.

Command2 handler works on changes made by Command1 handler, so how can we make them work sequentially?

Answer (score 2):

Sending messages from the handler should be done using the `context` passed into handler. When you use `bus.Send()` you're likely using `IMessageSession` rather than `IMessageHandlerContext`, which is equivalent to immediate dispatch.

Changing your code to the following should resolve it:

```cs
public async Task Handle(ICommand1 message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
   using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
   {    
       await HandleMessage1(message1, context);

       _session.Flush();
       tx.Commit();
    }   
}

private async Task  HandleMessage1(ICommand1 message1, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
    // Updating database
    ...
    // Sending other Command2 to separate handler
    await context.Send<ICommand2>(x =>
    {
       ...
    });
}
```

Comment: this "bus" variable is actually wraps IMessageHandlerContext reference, so in the end it calls IMessageHandlerContext.IPipelineContext.Send, we do not use ISendOnlyEndpoint

Comment: Ok. Make sure it's used with `await` as in the code I've showed.

Comment: inside it actually runs context.Send<ICommand2>(x => ...).GetAwaiter().GetResult(). could it cause the problem?

Comment: Inside what? You don't need a field, can flow the context and don't do `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: inside the "bus" wrapper. This wrapper exists to cover different call contexts, like web or legacy code, which is not on async framework, and not inside Nsb handler. I made the sample code simplistic, but HandleMessage1 is actually method of the service that can be run from varies contexts, not inside Nsb handler only. That's why we wrap it in our own "Bus" that can run from whatever. However for this particular case it picks up IMessageHandlerContext which we store on pipeline initialization.

Comment: You shouldn't use IMessageSession where IMessageHandlerContext should be used. Have a look at IUniformSession to help with this issue: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/uniformsession

Comment: No, they are used properly, IMessageSession is not used instead of IMessageHandlerContext. "Bus" is smart enough to understand host under which it's working. I'm just explaining why I can't pass IMessageHandlerContext inside like in your example. I'll try to run "await" instead of .GetAwaiter().GetResult()  tomorrow and let you know if it helps

Comment: I updated it to async/await like in your example, but it keeps dispatching messages immediately on Send() call

Comment: Could you share a reproduction on GitHub (or similar)? If not, support is where I'd send this question.

Comment: it's commercial code, unfortunately I'm not allowed to share it. Thank you anyway. At least now I know that I have not overlooked anything in Nsb documentation. There must be just something wrong in our own "Bus" implementation. I'll keep investigating